# Is possible to find the last Office's product key in office.com/myaccount?

Tags: html, dom, ms-office

I need to active the Office 2019 products by using a product key, there's a lot of machines to have the Office actived, and also there's only one key per machine. I use a @hotmail.com account to create a product key that appears at office.com/myaccount. The problem is that when I have about five keys already used, I spend a lot of time to find the one that was just created... So, is possible to inspect the page, or do another thing to find the last key that was added to the website??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  If it's not visible to the end-user, there is no point in sending it to the computer anyways.  I would suggest contacting Microsoft to see if they can help you.